# How to wrap a Reactor Flux stream with a Redisson lock and unlock?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, flux, reactor

I have a Flux stream that reads objects from the database.
For each of these objects, I have a processing function to be run.
I want the processing function to execute after acquiring Redis lock on ID of given object, and after processing release the lock (also if the processing function throws an error).

What's the easiest way in Flux to create such a stream?
Here is some code of my failed attempt at doing this with transform.
I could probably make withLock take a function which would be attached as `afterLock.flatMap(func)`, but I am looking for a solution that can avoid that.

I would like this to be as transparent to the rest of the stream as possible, and not require seperate attachment of lock and unlock functions, just one attachment that can do "lock-process-unlock".

```java
        private <T> Function<Flux<T>, Publisher<T>> withLock(Function<T, String> keyExtractor) {
          
            return flux -> {
                    Flux<T> afterLock = flux.flatMap(ev -> redis.getLock(keyExtractor.apply(ev)).lock(1000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).map(ret -> ev));
    
    // processing logic should be attached somewhere here
    
                afterLock
                        .flatMap(ret -> redis.getLock(keyExtractor.apply(ret)).unlock()
                                .thenReturn(ret)
                                .onErrorResume(e -> redis.getLock(keyExtractor.apply(ret)).unlock().thenReturn(ret)));
    
                return afterLock;
    
            };
        }
```

```
        Flux.just(someObjectFromDatabase)
                .transform(withLock(t -> t.id()))
                .flatMap(this::objectProcessor)
```

Answer (score 2):

One of the solution is to use `Mono.usingWhen` that allows to use async operations for resource supplier, resource closure and  cleanup.

```
Mono.usingWhen(
   lockService.acquire(key),
   lock -> process(),
   lock -> lockService.release(lock)
);
```

In our case we wrapped Redis lock into `LockService` that looks like the following

```
public interface ReactiveLockService {

    Mono<LockEntry> acquire(String key, Duration expireAfter);

    Mono<Void> release(LockEntry lock);

    interface LockEntry {
        String getKey();

        String getValue();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I added the code I came up with in the meantime, maybe someone will find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer @Alex, in the meantime I was able to come with something like this which is very flexible in terms of organizing the stream and resilent to failures (took me a while to cover edge cases...)
It can be used as a call to `stream.flatMap(withLock(..., processor)`

```java
    public static <T> Function<T, Flux<T>> withLock(
            long tid, String lockPrefix, int lockTimeMs, Function<T, String> keyExtractor, Function<Mono<T>, Flux<T>> processor, RedissonReactiveClient redis) {

        // If Redis lock or unlock operations fail, that will on purpose propagate the error.
        // If processor throws an error, lock will be unlocked first before error propagation.

        // tid has to be unique for each local task, it's a virtual "thread id" so if it's used concurrently locks will not protect the code

        return flux -> {
            Function<T, RLockReactive> getLock = ev -> redis.getLock(lockPrefix + keyExtractor.apply(ev));
            RLockReactive lock = getLock.apply(flux);

            Supplier<Mono<T>> unlock = () -> lock.unlock(tid).then(Mono.<T>empty());
            Supplier<Mono<T>> doLock = () -> lock.lock(lockTimeMs, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, tid).then(Mono.<T>empty());

            // Careful not to call map/flatMap on redis.lock/redis.unlock which returns Void and so it won't trigger on empty stream...lol!
            return Flux.concat(
                    Mono.defer(doLock),
                    Flux.defer(() -> processor.apply(Mono.just(flux))
                            .onErrorResume(err -> unlock.get()
                                    .onErrorResume(unlockError -> {
                                        err.addSuppressed(unlockError);
                                        // Propagate original processor error, but note the unlock error as suppressed
                                        return Mono.error(err);
                                    })
                                    .then(Mono.error(err)))),
                    Mono.defer(unlock)
            );
        };
```

Comment: That should do the job but still believe that `Mono.usingWhen` is cleaner approach especially for error handling